# Text editor with option to enclose selected text in tags

Tags: shortcuts, text, editor

I want to be able to select an amount of text and enclose it in some kind of a customisation tag. I used Geany, Atom, Gedit, Bluefish and I don't think any of them provide that option.

For example, if I had a math formula in tex: x \sub X, I'd want to mouse select that, than with a shortcut like ctrl + (something) put tags on both sides of it resulting in this: $x \sub X$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least `kile` is able to do this, you can define your own functions in `LaTeX`→`User Tags`→`Edit User Tags…`:

[image]

For your example, enter `$%M$` as shown here:

[image]

As you can see in the first screenshot, your first function is accessible with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, so just mark your text, press these keys and you're done.

Comment: Outside of being able to create user tags in Latex, is there a shortcut to encase selected text in said tag?

Comment: @m_highlanderish I added this above, the shortcut is given automatically. I don't know whether and how you can change the shortcut though.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm and is exactly what I wanted!!! I would give you the point you deserve but I don't yet have enough reputations! Props to you!

Comment: @m_highlanderish I don't really do this for the points, but accepting my answer gave me +15, so I'm good, thanks. ;)